# Adding text hyperlink to JSSOR Slide

Tags: jssor

Trying to figure out how to make one word in my text box on a JSORR slide a hyperlink.  The demo on the sight shows its possible, but no instruction on how to do it (I know how to make the image itself a hyperlink).

I grabbed this code by inspecting the sight, but it hasn't helped me....

"This is full customized content layer.​
                        Everything is allowed.​You can insert
                        
                            a link
                         or an image
                         here.
                    "*

---

My basic code is here. I want to make one word in the "homeslider01body" section a hyperlink....

```
    <!-- Slides Container --> 
    <div u="slides" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 482px; height: 536px; overflow: hidden;">

        <div><img u="image" src="home/_images/S01_01.jpg" />
        <div class="homeslider01title">Henrie and Betty-Loo</div>
            <div class="homeslider01body">Things are going well <br>Seriously Great!!
            </div></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="home/_images/S01_02.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="home/_images/S01_03.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<a>` slide.
Also, aou can add `<a>` element in a `<div>` slide.

```
<!-- Slides Container --> 
<div u="slides" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 482px; height: 536px; overflow: hidden;">

    <div><img u="image" src="home/_images/S01_01.jpg" />
    <div class="homeslider01title">
        <a style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;width:200px;height:30px;">Henrie and Betty-Loo</a>
    </div>
    <a class="homeslider01body">Things are going well <br>Seriously Great!!
    </a></div>
    <div><img u="image" src="home/_images/S01_02.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img u="image" src="home/_images/S01_03.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```